# Isotropic Universe and the mean of a 3-vector

Tags: cosmology

I am following Kushnir's [notes](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/physics/waxman/sites/physics.waxman/files/uploads/courses/AstroIICosmology/FRW-%20Doron.pdf) on the 'FRW Universe' and Section 9 on Page 12 begins with the following line: "From isotropy, the mean value of any 3-vector $v^i$ must vanish."

My understanding of *isotropy* is that the matter distribution of the Universe will be the same in all directions. However, I cannot see how we get from this definition of isotropy to the proposition that the mean value of any 3-vector must vanish. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three vector index $i$ runs over the spatial components, so the statement just means that some quantity is equal in all directions. E.g. if $v^i$ represents the flux/current of some fluid, then the mean value vanishing implies the flux/current is equal in all spatial directions. This is then the same as isotropy.

Comment: I feel as though I need a bit more of an explanation, as this is really just rewording the original question. Perhaps I should be more precise: what exactly are we talking about when we discuss 'mean value' here? Say, for the vector $(x,y,z)$, is it simply $(x+y+z)/3$? Or is it more complicated than that? A numerical illustration with an example flow would be very helpful to me here.

Comment: By mean value we really just mean the average magnitude in every spatial direction from each point.  So in Cartesian $(x,y,z)$ we'd just have $(0,0,0)$. Any other value would fail to be rotationally invariant (i.e. the magnitude of the vector would be non-zero) & therefore anisotropic. The only non-zero component of the vector is the time component.

Comment: Is there a more mathematically rigorous definition of this average? I feel as though this would help my understanding. Is it taken over a sphere?

Comment: I tried to give a physical picture in my answer as the mathematical definition is, well, trivial. The only rotationally invariant (so $SO(3)$ invariant) vector is the zero vector. Therefore spatial isotropy immediately implies $v^i=0$. For 'average' it's as simple as it sounds, just think of the resultant force/vector as one usually does in mechanics. I.e. add together all vectors at the point to get the average $v^i$. For example, $v^i_1 = (1,0,0)$ and $v^i_2 = (-1,0,0)$ gives $v^i_{avg} = (0,0,0)$.

Comment: That's better. Thank you. Does each $v^i$ identify a vector as opposed to the $i$th component then?

Comment: @wrb98 Ah okay, so it was the 'mean' bit that caused confusion. And yes, $v^i$ is a spatial 3-vector with three components for $i = \{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: I think my main confusion comes later in the cited test where it is stated that the current 3-vector $J^i = 0$. I think this example explains my problem: Suppose $N^i$ is the flux of particles in the direction of $x^i$ for $i = 1, 2, 3$. Then each $N^i$ is a scalar component of the 3-vector $(N^1, N^2, N^3)$. Then according to the above, swapping $J$ for $N$ should give $N^i = 0$ for $i = 1,2,3$. But the $N^i$'s here are not means in the way you have described, they are fixed values. Why have we gone from talking about means to what I consider a fixed current, $J(x,y,z)$ at a given point?

Comment: @wrb98 I think your use of vector indices isn't quite right, and I don't really understand what you mean with regards to 'fixed values'? Looking at those notes, it's as simple as saying isotropy requires no flux in any spatial directions, therefore any 4-current $J^{\mu}$ must have $J^{i}=0$. (Remember the currents here are 4-vectors, with some time dependence, so aren't 'fixed'.)